# Данные в series

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Нашёл пример круговой диаграммы написанной на javascript на сайте HighCharts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 61.41,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: 'Internet Explorer',
                y: 11.84
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.85
            }, {
                name: 'Edge',
                y: 4.67
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.18
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                y: 7.05
            }]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

А как мне сделать так что бы не писать на каждый новый элемент данные а сразу передать туда класс? Вот мои входные данные в контроллере которые на сайте в примерах используются для этой же диаграммы только без javascript а с использованием highcharts для dot.net

```
List<PieSeriesData> pieData = new List<PieSeriesData>();

            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "FireFox", Y = 45.0 });
            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "IE", Y = 26.8 });
            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Chrome", Y = 12.8, Sliced = true, Selected = true });
            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Safari", Y = 8.5 });
            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Opera", Y = 6.2 });
            pieData.Add(new PieSeriesData { Name = "Others", Y = 0.7 });

            ViewData["pieData"] = pieData;

            return View();
```

И вот как я их пытаюсь подкинуть в данные series:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["pieData"] as List<PieSeriesData>))
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Данные сериализуются, но почему то диаграмма не строится, а только шаблон для неё, что я делаю не так?
Вот как она выглядит в таком случае:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что находится на странице в data:

```
data: [{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"FireFox","Selected":false,"Sliced":null,"Y":45,"CustomFields":{}},{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"IE","Selected":false,"Sliced":null,"Y":26.8,"CustomFields":{}},{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"Chrome","Selected":true,"Sliced":true,"Y":12.8,"CustomFields":{}},{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"Safari","Selected":false,"Sliced":null,"Y":8.5,"CustomFields":{}},{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"Opera","Selected":false,"Sliced":null,"Y":6.2,"CustomFields":{}},{"ClassName":"","Color":"undefined","ColorIndex":null,"DataLabels":{"BackgroundColor":"","BorderColor":"undefined","BorderRadius":0,"BorderWidth":0,"ClassName":"","Color":"","ConnectorColor":"{point.color}","ConnectorPadding":5,"ConnectorWidth":1,"Crop":true,"Defer":true,"Distance":30,"Enabled":true,"Filter":{"Operator":"","Property":"","Value":null},"Format":"","Formatter":"","Inside":null,"Overflow":0,"Padding":"5","Rotation":0,"Shadow":{"Enabled":false,"Color":"","OffsetX":0,"OffsetY":0,"Opacity":0,"Width":0},"ShadowBool":null,"Shape":"square","SoftConnector":null,"Style":{"Color":"contrast","FontSize":"11px","FontWeight":"bold","TextOutline":"1px contrast"},"UseHTML":false,"VerticalAlign":2,"X":0,"Y":-6,"ZIndex":6},"Description":"undefined","Drilldown":"","Events":{"Click":"","MouseOut":"","MouseOver":"","Remove":"","Select":"","Unselect":"","Update":""},"Id":"null","Labelrank":null,"LegendIndex":null,"Name":"Others","Selected":false,"Sliced":null,"Y":0.7,"CustomFields":{}}]
```

Comment: добавьте к вопросу что получается в `data: ...` в сгенерированной  странице. Убедитесь что на выходе `Y` и `Name` и все оставшиеся поля в нижнем регистре. И что вообще нет других полей. Когда вы пополняете диаграмму через классы, сериализация скорее всего делается несколько иначе, чем просто `json.encode`

Comment: при такой ручной сериализации можете попробовать просто  `new { name: "Firefox", y : 100 }`  добавлять

Comment: @teran это получиться что я так же сделаю как в примере и мне придётся каждый элемент заполнять в ручную. Я сейчас покажу что в data но по другому у меня не получается серриализовать, Подскажите как можно по другому серриализовать что бы это сработало.

Comment: не понял вас. Если вы не используете по факту саму библиотеку в c#-коде, то данные подготавливайте также независимо от нее `pieData.Add(new  { name = "FireFox", y = 45.0 });`, и т.п.

Comment: @teran это просто тестовый вариант, в идеале эти данные будут из базы черпаться, и я не хочу ещё в js коде ещё раз делать такую же вещь, я хочу сразу данные подкинуть как это делается если писать чарт с помощью dot.net. Там можно просто подкинуть данные из viewdata и всё, а как это тут сделать?

Comment: ну да выберите вы `ViewData['pieData'] = db.Something.where(...).seletct( x => new { name... , y ....})` из базы, в чем проблема то?

Comment: @teran я вас кажется понял вы имеете в виду в контриоллере убрать после new класс `PieSeriesData` и просто сделать лист object. Я вас правильно понял? Если да то при такой реализации когда я конвертирую `as List<PieSeriesData>)` в data null, а если конвертировать так `as List<Object>)` так появляется ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` Хотя вроде там всё нормально, почти такая же как когда вы мне в другом вопросе с сериализацией помогали, вроде бы всё сериализуется но не работает.

Comment: в целом правильно. речь про контроллер. но в моей строке кода выше `List<>` этот вообще отсутствует. Если вам после выборки из базы надо еще что-то сделать с коллекцией, то объявите ее просто `var pieData =  db....`

Comment: @teran это понято, но в моём случае мне сейчас нужно именно к классу этого чарта привести, и так как вы подсказали я попробовал и чарт тоже не строится, не пойму уже что и делать с этим, что бы нормально данные подкинуть.

Comment: не знаю зачем вам приводить к этому классу. `as List<>` во вьюхе естественно надо тоже убрать, если не используете его в контроллере. Если не строится, то опять смотрите что в data получилось.

Comment: @teran вы можете сделать в этой теме чат что мы мы там могли пообщаться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79833/discussion-between-teran-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не используете непосредственные классы библиотеки в контроллере, а просто хотите подготовить и сериализовать данные в JSON для последующей передачи в JS, то не используйте встроенные классы Highcharts.

Создайте простые анонимные объекты

```
List<object> pieData = new List<object>();
pieData.Add(new { name = "FireFox", y = 45.0 });
pieData.Add(new { name = "IE", y = 26.8 });
```

Обратите внимание на регистр названий полей.

в представлении кастинг  `as List<PieSeriesData` также следует убрать.